# CSS - Simple box with multiple text

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make this:

http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_16129188181407418534.jpg

But it actualy looks like this:

http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_3290460671407418910.jpg?x

The thing is, I don't know how to change the size and position of 2 different text (in span and without span) without using tons of `div`s inside each other

I've tried something like this:

```
.box{
    display: block;
    background-color:#ff935f;
    color: white;
    font-size: 350%;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 290px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.box:hover{
    background-color:#ff6600;
}
.box img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.box span{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="images/box_icon.png">22 <span>Popisny text</span></a>
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="images/box_icon.png">22</a>
<a href="#" class="box"><img src="images/box_icon.png">22</a>
</p>
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a P tag, you should use Divs. P tags should be use for text and not as container. Note that I don't know if the box is suppose to be a link or not, but you could change the first div with the badge class for A href, just so you know.

See how I added two divs inside the main container div. This way it is easier to regroup content. You want to regroup the image and the number in the same container and let the subtext in its own container.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/g3b4ks5c/)

Html:

```
<div class="badge">
    <div class="upper-container">
        <img class="compass" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-line/100/Compass.png" alt="" />
        <h1>22</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="lower-container">
        <p>Popisny text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.badge {
    background:#ff6600;
    width:292px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.upper-container, .lower-container {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

.upper-container {
    height:100px;
}

.upper-container h1, .upper-container img {
    display:inline-block;
}

.compass {
    margin-left:103.5px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 85px;
}

.upper-container h1 {
    margin-left: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.lower-container {
    text-align:center;
}

.lower-container p {
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of psuedo elements for this:

HTML

```
<a data-label='some label text' data-count='22'>        
   <img width="68" height="67" title="" alt="" src="yourImage.jpg" />     
</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    background-color:#ff935f;
    color: white;
    font-size: 350%;
    width: 290px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    font-family:verdana;
}
a:before {
    content:attr(data-count);
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
}
a:after {
    content:attr(data-label);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-50px;
    font-size:15px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
a:hover {
    background-color:#ff6600;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```